# AWS SSL certificate installation issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, devops

I am facing some weird problem in aws. I have an instance running. I want to create SSL certificate for it. For that, I used certificate manager, load balancer and route 53 service of aws. Certificate manager to create a certificate. Load balancer for managing redirect and route 53 for creating various DNS records.

I learn all these from a YouTube tutorial. Via the same process, I get SSL certificate to one of my domains. But right now this process doesn't seem to work. My ec2 instance is working. My load balancer is working. Load balancer target group health check shows no error, but still my website load on HTTP. When i try to redirect from HTTP to https via htaccess file, website shows 'site can't be reached error'.

Here are the screenshot details

ec2 security group inbound rules (https://prnt.sc/ra3nsz)

Load balancer listener (https://prnt.sc/ra3o7w)

Load balancer target group (https://prnt.sc/ra3oeg)

Route 53 A record (https://prnt.sc/ra3p5o)

Certificate manager (https://prnt.sc/ra3wxa).

Comment: You should deploy your SSL cert(s) on your load balancer, not on your instance. Create HTTPS listener for that, and deploy cert for it.

Comment: @Marcin I already did it. I attached SSL certificate in the load balancer.

Comment: If so, why do you try  "redirect from HTTP to https via htaccess file"? It has nothing to do with ssl certificats on ELB?

Comment: I trird as none of the above steps seems to work.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding how ALB works. The HTTPS is only between your browser and ALB. Between ALB and your instances there is only HTTP. Thus changing anything on your instances has nothing to do with SSL on ALB.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But even ALB DNS has not open with https. It opens with 'Not secure status' while instance even doesn't show such type of warning. Instead of it, i got 'Site can't be reached error'. I knew that I did something wrong while configuring either the load balancer or route 53 but i didn't able to figure out that.

Comment: Maybe you still have HTTP listener on? What about SG for ssl port 443 for ALB?

Comment: I added both HTTP(80) and HTTPS(443) in SG. and in load balancer, I also added two listeners(http, https).

Comment: Site can't be reached is not a cert issue, there is something in port mapping config of your lb, if you could post or check port mapping from https on your ALB - issue would be somewhere there.
General algorithm: curl your instance (from within on http port - usually 80 - make sure it replies correctly), then point https ALB to that port and add redirect rule on http ALB. If you could provide exact config of your ALB and curl results, somebody would be able to say more.

Comment: @taleodor thanks. As per your suggestion, I added all the screenshot of what I did till now. Hopefully, someone will help me now.

Comment: lb configs looks ok, so can you curl port 80 from the instance?

Comment: @taleodor yes I able to curl port 80 instance as well as lb

Comment: Instead of http.access, redirect http to https in ALB rule itself. you can refer the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eNWM.png